# IDA 7.0 not recognizing plugins (Eg. ScyllaHide, IDAStealth)

Tags: ida

The problem I'm facing with the latest version of IDA (as of now) which is 7.0 is that it doesn't recognizes plugins, not even adding them in its Edit > Plugins menu tho this was not happening in IDA 6.x versions for me. As an example, my good old friend ScyllaHide is not showing up after I copy all the required files of it to the plugins folder of IDA and I forgot to mark the remaining files in the screenshot but HookLibraryx64.dll and the one under it (x86) and also InjectorCLI programs, NTApiCollection.ini (a must needed) and also ScyllaHide.ini are all present in this directory but it doesn't shows up, I watched a video in YouTube suggesting a solution and that was to edit the plugins.cfg file in the plugins directory and add the plugin file name and hotkey inside the config file manually, I tired that too but it didn't worked.

ScyllaHide works perfect on x64dbg and OllyDbg, I informed the maintainers of ScyllaHide in Github but they said its not the problem with the plugin. So if any of you had this experience, or can help me I'll be glad. 
And this problem is almost for all plugins, like FindCrypt2 and IDAStealth and x86emu.

[image: IDA 7.0 Plugins Directory]

Comment: 99% sure the plugins are, simply, not ported to IDA 7.0.

Answer (score 3):

There's a possibility that they might need to be ported to run in IDA 7.0 specifically, as per the following: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/7.0/docs/api70_porting_guide.shtml

Comment: @PsyCode can you post your solution in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, plugins aren't ported to IDA 7.0.

However, if you're looking for ScyllaHide, someone has modified the plugin to work with IDA version 7.

You can download it from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/notify-bibi/ScyllaHide-IDA7.5).

Copy contents/files within the `IDA` folder:

[image]

To your IDA `plugins` directory. then, restart IDA.

Now, ScyllaHide should be installed under *edit -> Plugins -> ScyllaHide* (or click on <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>):

[image]

And ScyllaHide should be working:

[image]